# Smart way to let function in .bashrc called from other bash script?

Tags: bash, function, call

I want to call fun1 in .bashrc from test.sh

cat test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
fun1
```

fun1 should be written as following format in .bashrc :

```
fun1(){
#do something
}
export -f fun1
```

I want to make all the functions (from fun2 to funm) in .bashrc be called from other bash script,to add `export -f funm` at the last line for every function,10 functions result in 10 lines `export -f funm` like in .bashrc file.

Is there a smart way to achieve the target?

Comment: Can't you just `export -f alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta`

Comment: `export -f fun{1..10}`?

Comment: You can't safely assume that every noninteractive shell will be a child process of an interactive shell, but relying on `.bashrc` having been invoked by some parent of a script makes exactly that assumption. Scripts can be called by cron jobs, by noninteractive remote shells, etc. [The answer by Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568595/14122) is absolutely the better practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bashrc` is [for interactive use](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files). Don't define functions there if you're going to use them in scripts.

If you want to make a file that contains functions to use in scripts, make it a separate file, and source that file from your scripts (and from `.bashrc`). Put the functions in e.g. `~/lib/bash/myfunctions` and put

```
. ~/lib/bash/myfunctions
```

in your scripts.